# Filtering data in NLTK

Tags: python, json, twitter, nltk

Following the NLTK documentation, here: http://www.nltk.org/howto/twitter.html#Extracting-Parts-of-a-Tweet

I am trying to filter tweets by the boolean tags `retweeted` and `possibly_sensitive` status. My example below only tries for the `retweeted` tag.

The output contains only the following `"id,text,retweeted.bool"`

```
input_file = "/blah/blah/blah/tweets.20171120-202012.json"
from nltk.twitter.common import json2csv_entities
with open(input_file) as fp:
    json2csv_entities(fp, 'tweets.20171120-202012.csv', 
                        ['id', 'text'], 'retweeted',['bool'])
```

The .json file is a newline separated json file with a number of tweet objects in it (which vary--some tweet objects do not have the `possibly_sensitive` tag, which only shows up when a tweet has a link). I suspect that this may be contributing to the problem.

Any ideas as to how I can get this json2csv_entities method to pull the `retweeted` and `possibly_sensitive` tags in?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

A sample of the input file is not practical to post here because it so long, but structurally it looks looks something like the following:

```
{"id":12312312, "text": "RT I love to eat bagels", "retweeted": true, "possibly_sensitive": false}
{"id":34523454, "text": "Here's a link to my sketchy website: http://wefewfwef", "retweeted": false, "possibly_sensitive": true}
```

Comment: Can you post a same of your input file in the question?

Comment: Sure, I added a simplified version of the status update JSON object. An exhaustive explanation can be found here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a line-separated JSON file line by line read each line of the file in as a string using the `loads()` method in python (load String).

I then wrote the following code to get at the keys I was looking for:

```
with open(input_file) as tweets_file:
    for line in tweets_file:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        # try catch handles for possibly_sensitive not being in the tweet metadata..
        try:
            sensitive = tweet['possibly_sensitive']
        except KeyError:
            sensitive = None
```

This worked wonderfully.